# Does Selectivizr visually enable border-radius or just add the selector?

Tags: css-selectors, css, selectivizr

Trying to get rounded corners to all browsers, including the bad one from version 8.

- I'm loading a js framework first.
- I do have a doctype declared.
- Selectivzr is loaded.
- All the paths are correct.

I still don't see the rounded corners on IE.

Does Selectivizr only enables the "css3 selector" but NOT the visual change that it may produce?

Comment: @Rob W - No demo available. A simple confirmation would sufice however. 1) Are anyone able to see border-radius effect applied using only the last Selectivzr, by simple doing: `border-radius: 14px`?  or, 2) are you using other tool (like CSSPie) to achieve that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selectivizr, as named and documented, only enables support for [CSS3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors). It does not enable support for CSS3 properties, such as `border-radius`.

To add support for `border-radius` to IE < 9, you're going to need to include an additional library, such as [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/).